# How can I stop my nightmare's hooves from burning everything?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, adnd-1e

My antipaladin's nightmare mount kept lighting on fire everything we'd ride over with its flaming hooves (e.g. shrubbery, commoners' huts, gnomes). While this is normally awesome, sometimes my allies prefer the two of us to be subtler. Out of grudging respect for my simple companions, I've been encasing my nightmare's hooves in makeshift metal boots. This makes my nightmare even angrier. I'd prefer an alternative.

Is there a printed means—preferably for *AD&D*—of allowing me or my nightmare to switch on and off my nightmare's flaming hooves?

Comment: The version we play is a bit of a smorgasbord of 2e, 3.5e, and a bit of 5e, but since most of it is 2e, I figured that was the best tag. Obviously any solutions will depend on my DM's approval. I'm just looking for ideas. As for the "feeling bad", I've edited the question to expound on that a bit.

Comment: Idea-generation questions don't really work in the Stack Exchange site format. As a rule they result in a list of ideas [that are all equally valid and correct](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2011/01/real-questions-have-answers/), which interferes with the site's mechanics. When just looking for ideas you want a [discussion forum](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/5449) instead of a Stack.

Comment: I am certain, given *2e*'s vast amount of material, that there're several printed ways to achieve what you want that can be evaluated based on a variety of criteria that will make a best solution ride to the top. It'll make the question more SE-friendly to specify print sources, though.

Comment: Oops. I said AD&D-2e when I meant AD&D. The question now reflects which PHB we use. Is that what you meant by "print sources"?

Comment: I've taken a crack at editing this. Make sure it's okay. Change it back or edit it more if it's not.

Comment: @HeyICanChan, That's perfect. :) I guess I tend to wax a bit too eloquent about the details that don't matter and leave out the ones that do. Thanks.

Comment: (I included the *preferably for AD&D* line in case you wanted to expand the question's mandate to other, less preferred system by including additional tags. With a question this narrow, getting an *AD&D* answer might be difficult, but a *2e* answer's plausible, and I can think of a couple of ways to do this in *3.5e* right now. However, I wouldn't add any tags unless there are still crickets in a couple of hours.)

Comment: 3.5 srd reads "A blow from a nightmare’s hooves sets combustible materials alight."  Is your GM specifically saying you're going around attacking everything as you move or is that a 2e/5e thing?  I could make this an answer but "don't go around attacking everything" sounds silly=)

Comment: @joedragons: Well, he's ruled (and I agree, I think) that striding/galloping across the ground counts as delivering a blow from the hoof to the ground.

Comment: Are you sure your DM *wants* you to solve this problems? It seems a bit like they want to inconvenience you until you get rid of the nightmare. Maybe because they regret the decision to let you have it because they consider it overpowered. In that case looking for a mechanical solution would be futile and you need to discuss with your DM about what choice they want you to take regarding your mount selection.

Comment: @Philipp: I'm pretty sure that's not it. For one thing, I just created this character, and the nightmare was far from the most overpowered mount I could've picked (the paladin in our party rides a gold dragon). For another, my DM has actually encouraged me to look for other solutions if I feel it's something my character would do (which I do). Plus, my DM isn't the kind to punish characters in-game without talking about it out of game.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The 3.5e magic item **[Horseshoes of the Zephyr](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/wondrousItems.htm#horseshoesofaZephyr)** will allow your nightmare to run *slightly* (an inch or two, if I remember right) above the ground. This is usually simply used to avoid leaving tracks, but seems to be a very efficient way to solve your problem by never touching the dirt or road. It requires *Levitate* to create, and so should be available at early levels.